# MS Access - Using one combobox to select a record and one combobox to edit a column in that record

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have the following two comboboxes: 
[image]

The left combobox gets it's values from one table and the right one from a different table. How would I even go about making it so when you select a record from the left combobox, and a value from the right combobox, and you click the tick button, the ID of the record in the right combobox gets written to a column in the record that you selected in the left combobox.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing something like this.  (assuming your ID's are numeric, and you're running from the same form)

```
sql = "UPDATE leftTable SET rightID = " & me!rightboxID & " WHERE leftID = " & me!leftboxID
```

Comment: would i implement this sql into VBA? I'm not really sure how to run SQL code on button click

Comment: You would use the Sql in the VBA code that runs on your click sub